# how to install ubuntu 12.04 from iso using wubi

Tags: installation, wubi

How to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS from the downloaded iso inside windows with using wubi installer.I am using windows xp and windows7 (dual boot).
I have tried putting wubi and iso in one folder but when I started installation with wubi it is downloading files from internet rather then taking from .iso. I want wubi that installs directly from iso rather than downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Note that wubi version must match with 12.04 version. Download wubi for Ubuntu 12.04 [here](http://download.cnet.com/Wubi/3000-2094_4-10701841.html). Put it together with .iso file you downloaded.

Comment: Thank you very much patel.it worked well.I am a newborn to linux. I have been searching for it for a month.THANKS

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, we always welcome newbies here.

Comment: if your problem is solved, accept my answer By clicking on True sign under downvote icon.